# WPS icons don't start at QuickLaunch box

Tags: wps-office

I downloaded WPS and it worked when I clicked it on the Menu. But when I put them on the quicklaunch, they did'nt start.

Comment: Hi, I personally do not have this issue. I downloaded here : http://wps-community.org/downloads, ran `sudo dpkg -i wps-office_11.1.0.8392_amd64.deb` then moved wps Writer from start to my launcher. now it is pinned. I clicked on it and it started up. what did you do?

Comment: I downloaded on the website that you gave and I installed it on the Software center on Lubuntu and it just stop at 70%, but when I stopped it, I saw that it was downloaded.

Comment: Should I reinstall it or there is a problem in the installation

Comment: I think you should try with the terminal method instead. maybe the terminal will show errors during instalation. yes uninstall and reinstall using my method.

Comment: Hello, I reinstalled it using the terminal, but when I remove the desktop icon (for example, WPS spreadsheet) the icon in the quick launch will not work.

Comment: what do you mean? what exaclty did you do was there an icon on the desktop or did you delete a .desktop file?

Comment: I selected the desktop icon and I deleted it and after that, the icon on the quick launcher didn't work. So I returned the icon and the app works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94911/discussion-between-jan-and-tatsu).

Comment: that's normal
perosnally i had no icon on the desktop
I'm guessing you have some non-ubuntu distro
where for WPS the .desktop file ends up on the desktop
you can put it elsewhere
but you cannot delete it
because that's what's pinned in the launcher
so the launcher would be pointing to nothing if the .desktop file is deleted